# Syncing contacts not in icloud group

Tags: icloud, data-synchronization, contacts, group

I have (for some reason I do not know) 68 contacts in iCloud and all the rest belong to another group. The 68 contacts are syncing correctly through iCloud.

How to I sync the other contacts which are in another group? I cannot see how I can add that group to the iCloud group.

I am on iOS16

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried exporting the other contacts and importing them to iCloud? This should sync them automatically after import.

Comment: When you go into *Contacts* (on your iPhone), there should be link at the top - *Lists*.  If you select it, it will open a new screen.  How many lists do you see?  Can you post a screen shot?